# Ordenar el paso del foco con la tecla Tab en Java

Tags: java

Quisiera saber si alguien tiene alguna idea de como ordenar el paso del foco entre los componentes de un panel? Ya probé de esta forma y no me dió resultados:

```
contentPane.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{
            btnInfoClientes, btnInfoClientesPep, btnInfoClienteEspe, btnInfoRubroEspe, btnInfoTransacciones, 
            btnInfoTransaccionesAmpl, btnInfoTransaccionesRec, btnInfoTransaccionesEnv, txtSucuTran, txtAno, 
            txtBoletaTran, btnBoleta, txtCodPersona, txtDocumento, txtNombre, txtApellido, btnBuscar}));
```

Ese sería el orden deseado, y según leí en algunos manuales, el método `setFocusTraversalPolicy` es una de las formas, pero no sigue el lineamiento especificado.
Otra forma que probé tambien es este método:

```
btnInfoClientes.setNextFocusableComponent(btnInfoClientesPep);
```

Pero aparte de estar deprecado el método, tampoco sigue la ruta deseada.
No se si influiría en algo, pero el Layout de mi JPanel es **Absolute:**

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Todos los containers en `JSwing` tienen un método que es `setFocusTraversalPolicy`.

Quedaría esto para un **panel** este seria el código:

```
panel.setFocusTraversalPolicy(
new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{textField_4, textField_3}));
```

Para un **contentpane** este seria el código:

```
contentPane.setFocusTraversalPolicy(
new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{textField, textField_2, textField_1}));
```

Como puedes ver, en el orden que pongas tus componentes, no solo `JTextField`, será el orden de tabulación que tengan.

Comment: Si, es la misma respuesta que forosdelweb, y si te fijas es lo mismo que hice en el código, pero no me reconoce la direccionabilidad que le estoy asignando.

Comment: Es más, creo que la respuesta está mal, ya que panel y contentPane hacen referencia a la clase JPanel, u otro Container, por lo que el código es el mismo para ambos

Comment: Pero comentas un panel, y estas utilizando contentPane, si no es así para ayudarte a reformular la pregunta.

Comment: No son dos mecanismos que compiten una JPanel es un Container (basta con ver la jerarquía de clases en la parte superior de los javadocs JPanel ).  JFrame.getContentPane()simplemente devuelve una Container para colocar el Components que desea mostrar en el JFrame.

Comment: contentPane es el nombre de la variable, si lees la pregunta dice claramente panel, osea, un JPanel. ContentPane no es una clase, es la referencia al contenedor del frame, por lo que haciendo getContentPane() te devolverá el JPanel utilizado, a eso me refiero con lo que es la misma cosa accediendo por un camino u otro el final siempre va a ser el JPane

Comment: entiendo, capaz y estoy mal orientado, ya que tenía entendido que el contentPane, osea, el Container es el JPanel que definis como contenedor

Comment: Porque en tu código definis tu contenedor así setContentPane(contentPane); tengo entendido que definis el contenedor de tu frame al JPanel definido

Answer (score -1):

Try this :
Search and search and it was so easy. I don't know if this is what you mean.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do9wIUsV8M8

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], si bien el vídeo podría contener la solución, un simple enlace no aporta una solución concreta. Puedes [edit] tu respuesta para agregar información relevante, 
adicionalmentee te encuentras en el sitio en español por lo que las respuestas deberían estar en español.